# When flying back from India to the US with eVisa + green card, does one have to take any action immigration-wise before the flight?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, check-in

Bob holds a French passport, a US green card, and is visiting India on an e-Visa (formerly known as tourist visa). He flew to India directly from the US. When flying back from India to the US, does Bob have to take any action immigration-wise?

I'm asking as Bob was told when checking in his flight back that he was supposed to have asked for some kind of clearance at any US embassy in India.

---

Answering the comments:

- Bob was allowed to check-in, after the airline employee called the embassy and waited 30 minutes for clearance. Bob was outside the US for three weeks. None of the travel documents had expired.
- The airline was Air India. Bob did indeed mention to the employees (4 employees got involved) that the green card should be enough to enter the US. Bob was told several times by the employees that he should have called the US embassy before taking the flight. No clear explanation was given to him despite repeatedly asking for clarification

Comment: Was Bob allowed to check in? Has his green card expired or has he been out of the US for an extended period of time?

Comment: @ZachLipton he was allowed to check-in, after the airline employee called the embassy and waited 30 minutes for clearance. He was outside the US for three weeks. None of the travel documents had expired.

Comment: Weird.  It sounds like the airline (or its employee) doesn't know what a green card represents.

Comment: @phoog it was Air India. Bob did indeed mention to the employees (4 employees got involved) that the green card should be enough to enter the US. Bob was told several times by the employees that he should have called the US embassy before taking the flight. No clear explanation was given to him despite repeatedly asking for clarification.

Comment: Perhaps they are under a delusion that someone with an ESTA-eligible passport needs some kind of explicit authorization to fly to the US without ESTA even if they have a visa or green card.  Or maybe the airline did submit the passport information to the US advance passenger information system, perhaps without including the green card in the record, and received a "do not board" message.

Comment: I just did a check on a few online travel document checking sites.  One of them indicated incorrectly that the documents were not sufficient because the passport must be valid for the duration of the intended stay (when in fact a passport is not even needed).  Perhaps there was something related to that.

Comment: @phoog AFAIK TIMATIC is what's used by all handling agents, and if anything, it will say "passports and other documents accepted", which doesn't really suggest that a passport is needed (it can refer to a green card too)

Comment: @Coke as I recall Timatic says "passport required" and possibly "visa required" and then has lists of "passport exemptions" and "visa exemptions"; both lists, of course, include the green card (form I-551).  But if the airline has some sort of logic in its own systems that is supposed to determine whether the given documents are okay (similar to traveldoc.aero) then there could have been a logical error leading to some misunderstanding.

Comment: @phoog Traveldoc (or IATA travel centre for that matter) isn't TIMATIC, only info based on it (and not always updated in time). Check-in staff use the actual TIMATIC, the text of which is the same no matter where it's used.

Comment: @Coke but do they use *only* timatic, or do airlines' systems have additional logic? When I was trying to check in for Sarajevo with my wife (the details I presume you recall) the agent said that *the system* would not issue the boarding pass to Sarajevo based on the documents she had presented.  But maybe he was lying. Also it was a Lufthansa desk but an Austrian final leg to Bosnia, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @phoog They only use TIMATIC, but there's something called TIMATIC AutoCheck, which, when the travel document is swiped, generates an OK/not OK result based on the TIMATIC info. IATA is careful to program it correctly for this purpose. As such, "your" check-in guy must've been using AutoCheck (not all airports have it, even in the EU), but the staff in  India likely didn't in "Bob's" case and/or are simply plain amateurs (far from uncommon)

Answer (score 5):

The check-in staff were amateurs, period.

Yes, you need to supply [SecureFlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Flight) data through the airline (this is done online when checking in at the latest), but no other clearance, not even a passport, is needed, only a valid Green card (or expired for that matter, if it's a 10-year card).

Comment: Thanks. "you need to supply SecureFlight data through the airline" -> Just to clarify: the passenger has nothing to do and the airline employees take care of everything related to SecureFlight?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You provide it, normally at the time of booking (it's your name, date of birth and sex)